# Django 'the view page didn't return an HttpResponse object.'

Tags: django-1.2

I am a newbie for Django. I have had an error like title during making pages.
my system information is Django1.2, Ubuntu12.

There already has been same as my error on stackorverflow - http://goo.gl/bK5msW

---

def register_page(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
                email=form.cleaned_data['eamil']
                )
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        return render_to_response('registration/register.html', variables)
```

Comment: Did the solution on the other question you referenced not work for you?

Comment: I have done reference on other page. but I have same error.

Comment: /Why are you using `Django 1.2`?

Comment: I read a Django book under 1.2ver. I also want to change higher version after being good django programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking like some issue with indentation, this should work for you.

```
def register_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                    username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                    password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
                    email=form.cleaned_data['email']
                    )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render_to_response('registration/register.html', variables)
```